# Shared Memory Only Updates After Syscall in Linux with C

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, ipc, shared-memory

I have two small programs. 'Server' creates some shared memory with shm_open and writes in a loop to the shared memory. 'Client' reads from the shared memory and displays the current value. 'Client' does not see the updates from 'Server' unless 'Server' makes a syscall like sleep or printf.

The below code only works with sleep(1) uncommented in Server.c:

Server.c

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int fd = shm_open("/SHM_TEST",  O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU);
    ftruncate(fd, 4096);
    
    unsigned char *ptr = mmap(0,4096,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
    
    while(1){
        for(unsigned short int i=0;i<256;i++){
            *ptr = i;
            //sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Client.c

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int fd = shm_open("/SHM_TEST",  O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
    unsigned char *ptr = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    
    int i = 0;
    while(1){
        printf("%d--%d\n", *ptr, i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I assume there is some caching going on or the "shared memory" isn't really sharing the same memory space. Is there a way to share memory without having to make any syscalls once it's setup? To have the two programs share the same physical memory? I don't care about race conditions, etc.

Comment: This is a race condition. You cannot write in one process and read the same thing in the other process without any synchronisation.

Comment: Try to use `__sync_synchronize()` instead of system call.

Comment: At a bare minimum, `ptr` needs to be `volatile`, otherwise the compiler will see writes with no reads (or vice versa) and optimize them out.  More properly, `_Atomic` types should be used.

Comment: @NateEldredge http://c.isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com/ is a handy reference.

Comment: @NateEldredge changing ptr to volatile or _Atomic type fixes my issue. Thank you!